# Llamar función desde radiobutton con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo en un formulario un campo `radiobutton` con opciones de si o no, necesito que al pulsar la opción si llamar a una función `javascript`.

Comment: ¿ Qué intentaste Criss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes otro ejemplo, esto hay muchas maneras de hacerlo usa el que mejor se adapte a las necesidades de tu proyecto.

```js
$(function(){

function funcion1() {
 console.log("SI");
}

// Ejemplo 1
$('input[value="si"]').on('change', this, function(){
 funcion1();
});

// Ejemplo 2
$('input#si').on('change', this, function(){
 funcion1();
});

// Ejemplo 3
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', this, function(){
 if($(this).val() == 'si') {
  funcion1();
 }
});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="web" id="si" value="si"> Si
<input type="radio" name="web" id="no" value="no"> No
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el evento `change` mediante el atributo `onchange` en el radio deseado.

**Ejemplo**

```js
function hacerAlgo() {
  alert('Has elegido Sí');
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="y" name="ask" value="y" onclick="hacerAlgo()">
<label for="y">Sí</label>
<input type="radio" id="n" name="ask" value="n">
<label for="n">No</label>
```